# Convert latitude longitude into continents and display charts - Google chart api

Tags: charts, google-api

I have the latitude and longitude for a set of users.I need to show a report, that gives the total number of users per continent.  I need to show the stats on the world map, by grouping the users by continent. The basic example in the google geo chart documentation - [Google Doc GeoChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) shows countries with a weight. I am in need of finding a way to show the continents rather than countries.

My final report should be like, Highlight each continent with a different colour based on the total number of users.

Comment: Found it! Made use of the Geocharts ressolution option, set it to sub continents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function drawGeoChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Region');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        data.addRows([
          [{ v: "154", f: "Europe" }, 500],
          [{ v: "155", f: "Europe" }, 500],
          [{ v: "151", f: "Europe" }, 500],
          [{ v: "039", f: "Europe" }, 500],

          [{ v: "021", f: "North America" }, 1000],
          [{ v: "029", f: "North America" }, 1000],
          [{ v: "013", f: "North America" }, 1000],

          [{ v: "005", f: "Latin America" }, 1500],

          [{ v: "143", f: "Asia" }, 2000],
          [{ v: "030", f: "Asia" }, 2000],
          [{ v: "034", f: "Asia" }, 2000],
          [{ v: "035", f: "Asia" }, 2000],
          [{ v: "145", f: "Asia" }, 2000],

          [{ v: "053", f: "Australia" }, 2500],
          [{ v: "054", f: "Australia" }, 2500],
          [{ v: "057", f: "Australia" }, 2500],
          [{ v: "061", f: "Australia" }, 2500],

          [{ v: "015", f: "Africa" }, 10],
          [{ v: "011", f: "Africa" }, 10],
          [{ v: "017", f: "Africa" }, 10],
          [{ v: "014", f: "Africa" }, 10],
          [{ v: "018", f: "Africa" }, 10]
        ]);

        var options = {
            resolution: 'subcontinents'                
        };
        var geoChart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart'));
        geoChart.draw(data, options);
    }
```